# Comparing 2 excel file python

Tags: python

I have tried to compare 2 excel files. It is working when it is in range but when not in range it is displaying an error.

Note: In range I mean, the 1st excel file has 5 rows and 5 columns, the 2nd excel file have more or less rows than the 1st excel file and same number of column.

How can I achieve this?

The code are as below:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import xlrd
rb1 = xlrd.open_workbook('a.xlsx')
rb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('b.xlsx')
sheet1 = rb1.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = rb2.sheet_by_index(0)
for rownum in range(max(sheet1.nrows, sheet2.nrows)):
    if rownum < sheet1.nrows:
        row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum)
        row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(rownum)
        for colnum, (c1, c2) in enumerate(izip_longest(row_rb1, row_rb2)):
            if c1 != c2:***emphasized text***
                print "Row {} Col {} - {} != {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2)
    else:
        print "Row {} missing".format(rownum+1)
```

Comment: Hi, could you please give context as to why and how you're trying to compare two Excel files? Are you trying to spot the differences? Or to tell if the files are the same?

Comment: Hello @CorentinPane, I want to spot the difference and print it. Even if, for example row5 in excel 1 is empty and in excel 2 row5 not empty or the other way around. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What error is it displaying? What line causes the error? Check [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Would this solution work for you? I just added a check to see which sheet has the lower number of rows.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import xlrd
rb1 = xlrd.open_workbook('a.xlsx')
rb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('b.xlsx')
sheet1 = rb1.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = rb2.sheet_by_index(0)
for rownum in range(max(sheet1.nrows, sheet2.nrows)):
    if rownum < min(sheet1.nrows, sheet2.nrows):
        row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum)
        row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(rownum)
        for colnum, (c1, c2) in enumerate(izip_longest(row_rb1, row_rb2)):
            if c1 != c2:***emphasized text***
                print "Row {} Col {} - {} != {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2)
    else:
        print "Row {} missing".format(rownum+1)
```

This is the sample output I get when I try to run it on two sample workbooks.

```
Row 15 Col 2 - Monkey != Cow
```

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'

Comment: Hmm I just tested the code out on my machine using two sample work books I created. It seems to work fine for me. Are you sure that sheet1.nrows are integer values. It looks like it is trying to compare a method to an int.

Comment: I updated the answer to show what sample output I get when I try to run it.